# SQL Developer: How do I increase the 'SQL Array Fetch Size' greater than the max. 500?

Tags: java, sql, class, jar, oracle-sqldeveloper

I’m looking for a way to increase the maximum records fetched for my queries in SQL Developer. I see that through the graphical interface I can increase it to 500 records (SQL Array Fetch Size) but I’m looking for a way to adjust that to a larger number.

*Is there a way to do this through the .jar file or its encompassing .class files?*

**Other important information:**

- I'm using SQL Developer on top of a SQL Server.
- I'm using SQL Developer version 3.2.09
- I'm using SQL Developer for Mac

Comment: _Why_ do you want to increase the record count returned?  Except for some types of reporting, getting that many records back is usually a sign you're doing something... awkward.  I would have assumed that, if this was meant to be set, there would be a parameter somewhere...

Comment: I work with an extremely large dataset that I generally pull into Excel to pivot and analyze.  There is nothing incorrect about my querying.  In my line of work, manufacturing, it's normal to have around 900 factories which all need to be analyzed.

Comment: ... But why are you trying to do this in Excel, as opposed to doing it in SQL Server itself?  And that information really should be part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

On the rusult view, press ctrl + end, then you will see all the result of your query. And the reason why sql developer set the limitation as 500 is to reduce the program that makes the program heavy and user's computer slow.